# typescript: assert string is not part of a union

Tags: typescript

I want to have typescript assert that a 'new' string is not part of a union, an existing set the string will be added to.

I'm looking for an independent, standalone line of code, but that's just a nice-to-have.

So, the simple, albeit contrived situation:

```
type FruitOptions = 'banana' | 'apple' | 'grape'
type NewFruitOption = 'pear'
// ^ being passed into a function ^

// Assert: FruitOptions does not contain NewFruitOption
```

I don't think sharing this is necessary, but this is the utility function I'm seeking to employ this technique on:

```
// These are inferred generics (since they come after the = sign), do not pass them in.
export const renameKey = <
  OldKey extends keyof T,
  NewKey extends string, // should NOT already be keyof T
  T extends Record<string, unknown>
>(
  oldKey: OldKey,
  newKey: NewKey,
  userObject: T
): Record<NewKey, T[OldKey]> & Omit<T, OldKey> => {
  const { [oldKey]: value, ...common } = userObject

  return {
    ...common,
    ...({ [newKey]: value } as Record<NewKey, T[OldKey]>)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if the `NewKey` extends `keyof T`, and if it does, set the parameter type to `never` so typescript will error:

```
newKey: NewKey extends keyof T ? never : NewKey
```

When you then change this valid call:

```
renameKey('lastName', 'clientLastName', formData)
```

To be invalid:

```
renameKey('lastName', 'lastName', formData)
```

You'll get a red underline on the second `'lastName'` saying: `Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'. ts(2345)`. It will also fail if you try to rename the key any other key that already exists:

```
renameKey('lastName', 'dateOfBirth', formData)
```

[image: error shown inside vscode]